# What is advantage of repeater control over grid view in asp.net C#?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, repeater

I have read many articles regarding difference between gridview and repeater. I come to know that gridview pattern is fixed in  and , where as repeater can provide customized HTML mark up. If I am not wrong, we can also customize HTML mark up by adding template field and placing table with customized design. In that tables we can place labels and other .net control and can get whatever we want. Then why to use repeater control.

I am confused in which scenario it can be preferred over gridview.

Comment: just try simple senario ... try to bind gridview and repeator control and go for view source and see u can understand better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In simple words we can say performance of repeater is far better than gridview. If you need basic rendering for read only items then its better to use repeater and if you need events , pagination and editable controls then you should go for gridview. Simpler controls with less in built functionality are speedy. you can do implement all functionalities of grid view to repeater but you have to do it manually.

So it depends upon you requirements either you need repeater or gridview

This discussion will be helpfull for you
http://forums.asp.net/t/1072020.aspx